# nexus 4 memory issue in lollipop

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

My nexus 4 on lollipop is facing some memory issue like app restart and it take a second to load the home screen after pressing the home button. the  i haven't  installed too many apps. The android system takes 1 GB ram. Is anyone facing he same issue?

[image]

Comment: Seems odd, my Nexus 4 system is using 413MB currently and I have 389 MB of running apps - [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GDkIK.png)